# DLL present in Nuget but restore failing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I have the following setup

Proj A
Proj B
Proj C

In Proj D, I added the project reference of Proj A, B and C. And I am packaging the Proj D as nuget. I have already followed the solution here https://github.com/nuget/home/issues/3891#issuecomment-377319939

When I check the nuget package generated, I can see the dlls of Proj A, B and C present in the lib folder. But when I try to add that nuget to my project, it tries to find the nugets of Proj A, B and C from all my feeds and fails.

I am new to this area so not able to figure out what is happening here. Need some help to understand this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this out and it works as expected from the comment you linked.

Make sure your project references have the metadata `PrivateAssets="all"`. Otherwise, you *will* get A, B, and C as NuGet package dependencies of package D.

The original github comment said to do this. It will not work.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\A\A.csproj" Type="project" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This worked for me (with the custom pack targets).

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\A\A.csproj" PrivateAssets="all" />
</ItemGroup>
```